# keeping a record of the number of rows

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, query-performance

Say we have a table "posts" in a MySQL database, that as its name suggests stores users' posts on some social media platform. Now **I want** to display the number of posts each user has created. A potential solution would be:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE` ....etc;

But To me -at least- this looks like an **expensive query**. wouldn't it be better to keep a record in some table say (statistics) using a column named (number_of_posts). I'm aware that In the last scenario I would have to update both tables (posts) & (statistics) once a post is created. What do you think the **best way** to tackle it?

Comment: I don't think such a simple query would be taxing, your ID will have a unique index on it. so a where condition on it will be very fast. Adding a trigger seems like overkill. #justmythough

Comment: What is in the `WHERE`?  That can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Queries like

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), user_id
   FROM posts
  GROUP BY user_id
```

are capable of doing an *index scan* if you create an index on the `user_id` column.  [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html). Index scans are fast. So the query you propose is just fine. SQL, and MySQL, are made for such queries.

And, queries like

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM posts
  WHERE user_id = 123456
```

are *very* fast if you have the `user_id` index. You may save a few dozen microseconds if you keep a separate table, or you may not. The savings will be hard to measure. But, you'll incur a cost maintaining that table, both in server performance and software-maintenance complexity.

For people just learning to use database software, intuition about performance often is grossly pessimistic. Database software packages have many thousands of programmer-years of work in them to improve performance. Truly. And, you probably can't outdo them with your own stuff.

Why did the developers of MySQL optimize this kind of thing? So developers using MySQL can depend on it for stuff like your problem, without having to do a lot of extra optimization work. They did it for you. Spend that time getting other parts of your application working.

Comment: No.  "Loose index scan" applies only to `MAX` and `MIN`, not `COUNT`.  `COUNT` require stepping through all the 'rows' in the index.

Comment: So here I have three options. either to go with COUNT(*).., or store a record (count) in some table and use a trigger to update it whenever a new post is created. or another -less secure- way would be making two (INSERT, UPDATE) quires each time a new post is made. but then which one is better when it comes to performance?!

Comment: Go with `COUNT(*)`. It's the simplest and plenty fast enough.  If you do something with multiple app queries or triggers, your program will become harder to maintain. (Ask me how I know this when you have some time.) In the future, when your `posts` table has fifty million rows in it, you can revisit your decision. Until then,  YAGNI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it.